# How should I choose a Muktzah Klaf?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

(Not to be confused with [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18724/5).)

I recently moved, and all my [Klafim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaf) got mixed up. I have some for Mezuzoth, some for Tefillin, and some for Sifrei Torah.  It just so happens that I was writing Sifrei Torah for [pixies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixie) (there is a tribe in the Amazon rainforest that considers itself one of the lost tribes and intends to be converted by the Israeli Chief Rabbinate after they are brought to Israel), so I'm using Klafim about the same size as my Mezuzoth and Tefillin.

Is there any reason to assume one size is Muktzah over the other or to assume a more expensive klaf is Muktzah over a less expensive one?  Also, since I'm the Sofer, I'll be the final seller, so should I use my cost or my sales price to determine the value (if it's relevant)? Is every Klaf Muktzah? Would it only be Muktzah once it's been assigned a use (or would it only be *non*-Muktzah once it's been assigned a use)?

How can I identify which of my Klafim are Muktzah and which are not?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: This is what happens when you have been learning the laws of Muktzeh with Daf Yomi and lack of sleep causes you to totally misread the title of a question, leaving you baffled when you try to make sense of the body of the question in, um, question.

Comment: I'm confused by the "pixies" link...nothing in the Wiki page says anything about Pixim(?) running around the Amazon, davening under the trees...

Comment: @Gary, they're of Celtic descent, but they fled in the 17th Century because of religious persecution.

Comment: A Sefer Torah is an Avi Avos HaMuktzeh; whatever touches it becomes an Av HaMuktzeh, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The question is Muktza Machmas Chisoron

Comment: @GershonGold, then you should kis it and make it all better.